# Пропускать ноль при выводе текста в консоль

Tags: java

Код действует, как имитация работы лифта. При вводе в консоль числа, выводится последовательность этажей от текущего до введённого в консоль. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы консоль не выводила нулевой этаж, а после 1 сразу шёл -1.

```
public class Elevator {

private int currentFloor = 1;
public int minFloor;
public int maxFloor;

Elevator(int minFloor, int maxFloor) {
    this.minFloor = minFloor;
    this.maxFloor = maxFloor;
}

public void moveDown() {
    currentFloor = currentFloor > minFloor ? currentFloor - 1 : currentFloor;
}

public  void  moveUp() {
    currentFloor = currentFloor < maxFloor ? currentFloor + 1 : currentFloor;
}

public int getCurrentFloor() {
    return currentFloor;
}

public void move(int floor) {


    if (floor > maxFloor | floor < minFloor | floor == 0) {

        System.out.println("Несуществующий этаж!");

        return;

    }

    if (currentFloor != floor) {

        while (currentFloor < floor) {

            moveUp();

            System.out.println("Этаж: " + currentFloor);
        }
    }

    if (currentFloor != floor) {

        while (currentFloor > floor) {

            moveDown();

            System.out.println("Этаж: " + currentFloor);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Elevator elevator = new Elevator(-3, 26);

while(true) {
    System.out.print("Введите номер этажа: ");
    int floor = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    elevator.move(floor);
}

}
```

}

Comment: Так пропускайте ноль, в чём проблема то? Даже код уже написан весь, одно условие добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или вот так

```
public void moveDown() {
    currentFloor--;
    if (currentFloor == 0) {
        moveDown();     
    }
}

public void moveUp() {
    currentFloor++;
    if (currentFloor == 0) {
        moveUp();     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например можно изменить методы `moveDown()` и `moveUp()` вот так:

```
public void moveDown() {
        if (currentFloor == 1) {
            currentFloor -= 2;
        } else {
            currentFloor -= 1;
        }
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        if (currentFloor == -1) {
            currentFloor += 2;
        } else {
            currentFloor += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: почему бы вместо ненужного вычисления не присвоить сразу -1 или 1? ``currentFloor = -1``  и ``currentFloor = 1;``